# RESTful API : Should we create separate controller to manage many-to-many relationship

Tags: rest, asp.net-core-webapi

What is the Best Rest practice to manage Many to many relationship in .net Core API

Here are 2 example models and mappings.

**Users  and Teams**

- One user can belong to many Teams
- One Team can have many users

So to model this relationship we have a mapped table with UserTeams (Id, UserId, TeamId)

**Scenario 1.**
When User is created ,Its associated teams will be assigned to it with POST

POST /users/user

**Scenario 2**
We need to provide the option in Teams to add more users in a given team.

PUT /teams/{1}/users *[provide a list of user ids]*

**Scenario 3**
Add more Teams for a particular user

PUT /users/{1}/teams *[provide a list of team id]*

What is REST best practice should we use the same pattern as mentioned above or to Create a new Controller UserTeams to manage user and teams relationship.

**One more scenario**

In Get Teams, We need to get the list of all Users. This will be the only GetbyId on TeamsController so should we just call it

Get /teams/{id}

or

Get /teams/{id}/detail   *[As it also include User Details]*

Comment: Either embedding links to users in the team resource, or creating a separate 'users collections per team' is a valid design choice.

Comment: Teams and Users these 2 are separate controller, however i am confused with the creating a separate controller to manage this relationship , i m more comfortable by adding routes in each controller to get the related list. Just want to know Rest best practice in this regard

Answer (score 0):

I can come up with these 4:

1.) membership in teams

```
GET /teams/{tid}/users
PUT /teams/{tid}/users [{uid1},{uid2},...]
DELETE /teams/{tid}/users/{uid}
```

2.) membership in users

```
GET /users/{uid}/teams
PUT /users/{uid}/teams [{tid1},{tid2},...]
DELETE /users/{uid}/teams/{tid}
```

3.) membership with membership id

```
GET /memberships/?user={uid}&team={tid}
GET /memberships/?user={uid}
GET /memberships/?team={tid}
GET /memberships/{mid}
POST /memberships/ {uid,tid}
DELETE /memberships/{mid}
```

4.) membership with user id and team id

```
GET /memberships/user-{uid}/team-{tid}
GET /memberships/user-{uid}/
GET /memberships/team-{tid}/user-{uid}
GET /memberships/team-{tid}/
POST /memberships/ {uid,tid}
DELETE /memberships/user-{uid}/team-{tid}
```

You can support all 4 in parallel if you want to.

Now that I think about it, I can come up with another 2:

5.) membership in teams

```
GET /teams/{tid}/members
PUT /teams/{tid}/members [{mid1},{mid2},...]
DELETE /teams/{tid}/members/{mid}
```

6.) membership in users

```
GET /users/{uid}/memberships
PUT /users/{uid}/memberships [{mid1},{mid2},...]
DELETE /users/{uid}/memberships/{mid}
```

So what I don't like in the 1.) and 2.) solutions that we are talking about memberships here and the memberships belong to both the teams and the users. Since path is for describing a hierarchy the 1.) and 2.) tells me that teams contain users and users contain teams, which is not true, because they are independent of each other. The teams can exist without a certain user and the user can certainly exist without a team. So I would rather talk about memberships which cannot exist without teams and users, but both teams and users can exist without memberships. Well it is possible to have an empty team...

So I would go with the combination of 3.) + 5.) + 6.) if I want to be very verbose. It is important to have the right model here, because if you have memberships, you can add membership properties like since when, who allowed it or who invited the new member, when it ended, how much did they pay for it, what is the title of the member, etc. So it is really important to have the right model here. Ofc. if all you want to manage is the existence of the membership at the current time, then probably 1.) and 2.) is ok too.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, yes at the moment we are not managing any additional detailed related to membership. So 1) and  2) are okay for now.

Comment: Now we have the scenario like you mentioned in 5) and 6)  so should we create 2 separate controllers to manage this workflow? as Request/Response models for both are different. I was just trying to clear my concept as when we should go for a separate controller ?