# Obtaining resource through relation

Tags: rest, restful-url

I have two entities that have a many-to-many relationship with each other. Namely a Machine and a Tool. A Tool can be inside the inventory of zero or multiple machines, therefore the many-to-many relations.

Now I need to query the Machines where a particular tool is inside them. At the moment I have a resource /machines/ where I can get a list of machines or /machines/{id} to get a particular machine. The first method already has an implementation to search for machines. Through the name, type and other attributes.
But for this query I need to query in one way, namely: "Which Machines have this Tool inside of their inventory?"

How do you apply this in a meaningful Restful way making it clear for the client that they have two options to query Machines: (1) through attributes, and (2) through the tool inside the inventory? This implementation will not be shared, thus a client cannot expect to find machines that have a particular tool inside its inventory AND filter by name or type. It's one or the other.

Thus, when I offer an API that has the following resource(s)

- /machines?toolid=GUID
- /machines?name=SOME-NAME
- /machines?name=SOME=NAME&type=SOME-TYPE

It's logical to expect that query parameters can be combined, thus the combination of toolid and name is also a possibility. But that isn't the case.

How can I design the API in such a way that it is clear to the client that they have two options to search for machines and what the use cases are of the two query options?

@Update 22-09-22:
I have let it sunk in further and came to the conclusion that on repository level I'm going to introduce two methods, thus there I'm already introducing a seperation:

```
interface IRepository {
    function findBy(string $name = null, string $type = null): array;
    function findByToolInInventory(string $toolId): array;
}
```

Is it then good practice to introduce a operation beside /machines that delivers the result from another query. For example: /machines/wheretoolininventory/{toolId} ?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73709477/607033

Comment: Repository is in a different layer 3 layers below URI at least. It should not affect URI design at all.

Comment: You could provide two hyperlinks (in the response to a former request) that use URI templates to inform the client about the allowed parameters and use different link relations to describe the two use-cases.